# Remove the whole set of characters after the last space from the multiple strings

Tags: c#

I have multiple spaces in between string.I want to remove the set of character after the last space(if last set of character length is less than 4).

```
string firstString = "test value1";
string secondString = "test value che";
string thirdString = "test value che ck3"
```

Expected result:

```
firstString = test value1
secondstring =test value
thirdstring = test value che
```

Comment: Where is the code, that you've tried?

Comment: `String.LastIndexOf` should get you going

Comment: This doesn't make sense... the expected results are not in line with you explanation. "I want to remove the character after the last space" but on your expected result you removed the whole set of characters not a character on your 2nd and 3rd string

Comment: As told by @MichaelRandall String.LastIndexOf for the space, and the you can compare the index with the string length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should satisfy your examples.

```cs
public static string CleanString(string value)
{
    var lastSpaceIndex = value.LastIndexOf(' ');

    if(lastSpaceIndex < 0) return value;

    var residue = value.Substring(lastSpaceIndex);

    if (residue.Length <= 4)
    {
        return value.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;  
  
namespace DateTimeFormatInCSharpSample  
{  
    public class Program  
    {  
        public static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            string firstString = "test value1";
            string secondString = "test value che";
            string thirdString = "test value che ck3";
            
            var p = new Program();
                        
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(firstString));
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(secondString));
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(thirdString));
        }  
        
        public string getNewString(string str)
        {
            var spaceIndex = str.LastIndexOf(" ");
            return (str.Substring(spaceIndex).Length < 4) ?  str : str.Substring(0,spaceIndex);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` will do:

```
  static string MyRemove(string value, int maxSize = 3) {
    int lastIndex = value?.LastIndexOf(' ') ?? -1;

    return (lastIndex >= 0 && lastIndex >= value.Length - maxSize - 1)
      ? value.Substring(0, lastIndex)
      : value;
  }
```

Demo:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "test value1",
    "test value che",
    "test value che ck3",
    "test and test",
    null,
    " abc",
    "abracadabra",
  };

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-25} -> {MyRemove(test)}")));
```

Outcome:

```
test value1               -> test value1
test value che            -> test value
test value che ck3        -> test value che
test and test             -> test and test
                          -> 
 abc                      -> 
abracadabra               -> abracadabra
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [.Net FIddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xk9RA3) for you:

```
namespace DateTimeFormatInCSharpSample  
{  
    public class Program  
    {  
        public static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            string firstString = "test value1";
            string secondString = "test value che";
            string thirdString = "test value che ck3";
            
            var p = new Program();
                        
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(firstString));
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(secondString));
            Console.WriteLine(p.getNewString(thirdString));
        }  
        
        public string getNewString(string str)
        {
            var spaceIndex = str.LastIndexOf(" ");
            return (str.Substring(spaceIndex).Length < 4) ?  str : str.Substring(0,spaceIndex);
        }
    }  
}
```